# Read the stream file with PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I would like to read a stream file with PHP (if possible), which is constantly being expanded. The file is a .json where new lines are added at irregular intervals.

Currently I have tried the following:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen ("https://domain.de/stream.json", "r");
while ( $inhalt = fgets ($handle, 4096 ))
{
  echo "<li> $inhalt ";
}
 
fclose($handle);
?>
```

The basic idea works, but only as long as new lines are added. If, for example, no new line is added for 20 seconds, the end of the loop is reached and the loop ends automatically.

How can I realize that the loop is not terminated but waits for new lines?
Is this even possible with PHP alone or do I have to use cURL or similar?

I would be very grateful for help and an example how it could work.

Kind regards and thanks in advance

Comment: I assume the JSON file is also sent as a stream and you are not just trying to edit a file thats being sent currently?

Comment: Right. The JSON is sent as a stream.

Comment: Does it change anything if you run `set_time_limit(0)` before the http request? (If it does, Ill write it as an answer so people can find it)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The problem seems to me to be that the while loop is terminated once the end is reached.
Therefore it loads page permanently. Once the end has been reached, the loop is terminated and future entries are unfortunately no longer displayed.

Comment: Ok, I know what the issue is, Ill try to figure out a fix

Comment: Thank you very much. You'd help me a lot with that.

Comment: When should the reader be closed?

Comment: Preferably only when the browser tab is closed.
As long as the page is open, the latest entries should always be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$handle = fopen ("https://domain.de/stream.json", "r");
while ( TRUE )
{
  $inhalt = fgets ($handle, 4096 );
  if($inhalt === FALSE) {
    continue;
  }
  echo "<li> $inhalt ";
}
 
fclose($handle);
?>
```

How about instead of quitting when you dont get the bytes, instead just run infinitly and ignore everytime there is no data.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work as hoped. Now the page loads permanently without showing anything.
I'm also a bit surprised that the page loads permanently, that doesn't look healthy.

An acquaintance told me that I should rather do it with cURL, but unfortunately I don't know anything about that.